# Unable to migrate database in Entity Framework 4.3.1 or higher

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

**EDIT:** I know this question was closed because of the lack of information provided by recently I have encountered the issue that is exactly the same as described in the below code sample.

```
DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration = new Configuration();
DbMigrator dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
dbMigrator.Update();
```

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.

**EDIT (Continuation):** This exception was caused by the call to Update method without parameters (I did reflected the method and found out that without providing the name of the target migration EF expects that you database and model are compatible with the Automated migrations.

Calling the Update("") solved my problem. Hope this edit will help someone.

Comment: I am having this same problem when trying to run migrations on App_Start

Answer (score 2):

The error exactly says you what you have to do:

```
configuration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```